# Loading CSV into List using BindingSource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv

I'm trying to load a csv file containing a list of 'Workstations' into a List using a BindingSource.  Here is what I have right now.

```
    OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
    List<Workstation> invList = new List<Workstation>();
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = invList;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "display";

    public class Workstation
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string serviceTag { get; set; }
        public string display
        {
            get
            {
                return name + " | " + serviceTag;
            }
        }
        public string type { get;set; }
        public string os { get; set; }
        public string make { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public int hd { get; set; }
        public int ram { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }
    }



private void resume()
{
    try
    {
        filePath = of.FileName;

        var loadedWorkstation = new Workstation();
        string[] line = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        List<string> doc = new List<string>();

        for(int x = 0;x < line.Length; x++)
        {
            doc = line[x].Split(',').ToList();
            loadedWorkstation.name = doc[0];
            loadedWorkstation.serviceTag = doc[1];
            loadedWorkstation.make = doc[2];
            loadedWorkstation.model = doc[3];
            loadedWorkstation.ram = Convert.ToInt32(doc[4]);
            loadedWorkstation.hd = Convert.ToInt32(doc[5]);
            loadedWorkstation.os = doc[6];
            loadedWorkstation.location = doc[7];
            loadedWorkstation.type = doc[8];
            loadedWorkstation.ip = doc[9];
            loadedWorkstation.notes = doc[10];
            invList.Insert(0, loadedWorkstation);

            bs.ResetBindings(false);
            listBox1.DataSource = bs;
            }

        }
}
```

The problem I'm having with this is that the csv file looks like this:

```
Dave's PC,19NMX32,Dell,Optiplex 2010,0,0,,Office Desk,,10.10.77.138,
Blake's PC,20NMX12,Dell,Optiplex 3020,0,0,,Office Desk,,10.10.77.136,
John's PC,4NMX17,Dell,Optiplex 3020,0,0,,Office Desk,,10.10.77.131,
Jake's PC,12NMX32,Dell,Optiplex 3020,0,0,,Office Desk,,10.10.77.132,
```

and when I load it, the List and listbox show this:

```
Dave's PC | 19NMX32
Dave's PC | 19NMX32
Dave's PC | 19NMX32
Dave's PC | 19NMX32
```

Comment: You're setting the datasource within the loop?  Once per line read?  Y?

Comment: @Will I changed it.  It was just for testing reasons that I had it inside the loop.

Comment: May I ask why I was downvoted?  I'd like to know for future reference.

Comment: Probably because it's a "stupid error" (we all make them, no offense) that would have been solved with some debugging.  Or maybe it's because it is Monday.  Who knows?

Comment: @Will Makes sense. I was doing this at 4:30 on a friday... so I was probably thinking too much about the weekend.. Anyways, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move this line

```
var loadedWorkstation = new Workstation();
```

inside the loop

```
for(int x = 0;x < line.Length; x++)
{
    doc = line[x].Split(',').ToList();
    var loadedWorkstation = new Workstation();
    loadedWorkstation.name = doc[0];
    ....
```

Your current code always use the same instance of a `Workstation` class. You add repeatedly this same instance for every line in the file.

Inside the loop you don't build a new instance but change the properties of the only Workstation instance created. This results, at the end of the loop, with this lonely instance equal to the last line loaded and your list showing the same reference for every item.

As noted in the comment under the question, probably you could also move these lines

```
  bs.ResetBindings(false);
  listBox1.DataSource = bs;
```

outside the loop

Comment: Wow, cannot believe I didn't catch that when debugging.  That worked... Thank you so much.

Comment: The `Debugger is just like the Lord`  they both work in mysterious ways when used properly..